# Insert data to sqlite from json file

Tags: javascript, json, sqlite

What it's wrong here,i cant insert:

```
 $.getJSON('file.json', function(data) {   

 tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO table (DATE, LIB, BID)  VALUES("+data.date+","+data.Lib+","+data.BID+")");

      });
```

Comment: did you found the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need quote the data you want to insert if they are string type.

```
"INSERT INTO table (DATE, LIB, BID)  VALUES('"+data.date+"','"+data.Lib+"','"+data.BID+"')"
```

And the below is better.

```
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO table (DATE, LIB, BID)  VALUES(?,?,?)", [data.date, data.Lib, data.BID]));
```

Comment: Then fix the syntax error, with only part of the code, nothing can be figure out.

Answer (score 0):

i tried this code but it does not execute the query in the function(data)

kept the query before and after the function and it worked

so had pass data to another function to execute the query